# IntelliJ doesn't list changes when comparing working copy to SVN's trunk, but tracks them in Local Changes

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, version-control

We are using IntelliJ 2017.1.3 Community Edition. A colleague is working from home, merging changes from a branch into his local working copy of trunk.

In the `Version Control` menu's `Local Changes` tab, all files that were changed are listed. However, when he right-clicks on the (multi-module maven) project's root in the `Project` menu (on the left), and selects `Subversion` > `Compare with Branch...` > `trunk (trunk)` from the context menu, the `Compare of 'http://svn.example.com/foo/trunk/bar and '/baz/trunk/bar'` window tells him there are *no changes found*.

When I try the same thing, I get a tree listing of files I changed.

Why does IntelliJ tell him there are no changes when he tries to compare with what's on the SVN server, but it's tracking the changes in the `Local Changes` tab correctly, offering to commit them from the `Commit` dialogue?

Update: It does work for any branch - it goes off, thinks about it, then displays the list/tree of changed files. It just doesn't do it for trunk, and suspiciously, it "fails" instantly...

Answer (score 0):

Local changes show file changed in local working copy - equivalent of the `svn status` command. The compare action shows you result of a different operation - `svn diff`. 
So results could be different, depending on various factors - paths, trunk/branch URL configuration, possible errors. 
This does not happen to me though. Maybe there are some errors/warnings shown?